# For Classes : Set Overview and Description to my classes

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

When you use any class or any function in eclipse, there's small dialog that will show you some information about the class or function that you selected.

My question is : how can I make the same thing for my classes and functions? I have been unable to find any information on how to do this.

**Examples:**

*For Classes : `ArrayList`:*

All elements are permitted, including `null`.

> This class is a good choice as your default List implementation.
>   Vector synchronizes all operations, but not necessarily in a way
>   that's meaningful to your application: synchronizing each call to get,
>   for example, is not equivalent to synchronizing the list and iterating
>   over it (which is probably what you intended). CopyOnWriteArrayList is
>   intended for the special case of very high concurrency, frequent
>   traversals, and very rare mutations.
>
> **Summary**

*For Functions: `Log.d()`:*

> public static int d (String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)  Since: API
>   Level 1  Send a DEBUG log message and log the exception.
>
> **Parameters** tag  Used to identify the source of a log message. It usually identifies the class or activity where the log call occurs. 
>   **msg**  The message you would like logged. 
>   **tr**  An exception to **log**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add Javadoc comments to your classes, methods, and variables, Eclipse should pop up local help for them the same as the built-in classes. You can read about how to write documentation for the Javadoc tool [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

Comment: **Exactly what I want ^_^** Thanks